# Hand zur Muschel / zum Trichter formen

Tags: single-word-request

Wenn man die Hand in Form einer Schale hinters Ohr hält, wie nennt man das?

[image]

Ich finde in Büchern die Formulierungen "formte die Hand zum Trichter" und "formte die Hand zu einer Muschel", bin aber über beide etwas unglücklich.

Ein Trichter ist rundherum geschlossen, und wenn man "die Hand zum Trichter formt", stelle ich mir eher vor, dass die Finger zur Handfläche herumgebogen sind und den Daumen berühren, wie beim "o" der Gebärdensprache:

[image: sign language o]

Was mich an "formte die Hand zur Muschel" stört, kann ich nicht genau sagen. Vielleicht, weil ich das so noch nie gehört habe und es mir unvertraut vorkommt.

Wie sagt man richtig?

---

Ich sage normalerweise: Die Hand ans Ohr legen. Aber diese Formulierung suche ich nicht. Ich suche eine gebräuchliche Formulierung, die die Form der Hand beschreibt.

Comment: Geht es dir nur um die Form der Hand oder um die Form der Hand, wenn sie gleichzeitig am Ohr liegt?

Comment: @Pollitzer Um die Form der Hand, wenn sie ans Ohr gelegt wird.

Comment: Wer sagt, dass ein Trichter rundherum geschlossen ist?

Comment: @userunknown Beispiel bitte.

Comment: Ein durchschnittener Rundtrichter, der an eine Wand gehalten/montiert wird, die ihn auf der anderen Seite abschließt. Oder ein Trichter, der immer schräg gehalten werden muss, so dass eine Rundumschließung  behindern würde. Ich würde mir weder über die Bezeichnung Muschel, noch über Trichter Sorgen machen.

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde *die Hand wölben* oder *eine gewölbte Hand* benutzen und damit Deinen Satz erweitern:

> Die *gewölbte* Hand ans Ohr legen.

Die Seite *[The free dictionary](https://de.thefreedictionary.com/w%C3%B6lben)*  führt diese Bedeutung auf:

> 2. Hand in Form eines Bogens halten *Sie wölbte ihre Hand schützend über das Küken. etw. in der gewölbten Hand halten gewölbt*

Comment: Ja, fürs übers Küken. Aber am Ohr... man kann es sagen, aber es klingt doch überraschend, finde ich.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Küken, Ohren... die Form der Hand ist doch identisch, und um die geht es doch, wenn ich das richtig verstehe

Answer (score 3):

Diese Form der Hand nennt man

> geöffnete Hand

bzw.

> halb geöffnete Hand

wenn sie deutlich gekrümmt ist.

Für deinen Fall könnte man also sagen:

> Um zu signalisieren, dass er nicht verstanden hatte, legte er die [halb]
>   geöffnete Hand ans Ohr.

Comment: Ja, so geht es.

Comment: Nicht schlecht. Google findet so eine Handvoll Belege in gedruckten Büchern für "geöffnete Hand ans/hinters Ohr". Also nicht supergebräuchlich, aber bisher die schönste Formulierung. Danke dafür.

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube, man braucht einen Erzählfluß-Kontext dazu. Probieren wir's mal so:

> "Morgen wird's wieder regnen", sagte Brigitte. "Wie bitte?", fragte Heinz, der nicht mehr der jüngste war, und hielt die Hand hinters Ohr.

Klingt halbwegs akzeptabel, finde ich. Aber die erste Version, die mir eingefallen wäre, wäre auch dein *legte die Hand ans Ohr*.

Vielleicht noch eine Variante, aber die ist schon sehr gekünstelt:

> "Morgen wird's wieder regnen", sagte Brigitte. "Wie bitte?", fragte Heinz, der nicht mehr der jüngste war, und machte die Hand zur Ohrmurschel.

Naja. Klingt etwas gezwungen. - Oder wenn man's aus irgend einem Grund von der technischen Seite her angehen will - was dann vielleicht Sinn ergäbe, wenn Heinz ein Fernmeldetechniker oder Akustiker wäre:

> "Morgen wird's wieder regnen", sagte Brigitte. "Wie bitte?", fragte Heinz, der nicht mehr der jüngste war, und hielt die Hand als Reflektor hinters Ohr.

Solche Varianten wären dann akzeptabel, wenn der Rest der Geschichte einen solchen Kontext nahelegt. Einfach so aus der Luft gegriffen wären sie unmotiviert und damit störend.

Comment: Ich befürchte, diese Antwort beantwortet die Frage nicht, sondern explizit die, die der Frager eben nicht beantwortet haben will.

Comment: @tofro   Wieso? Ich habe doch eine alternative Formulierung geliefert? Dass die Form der Hand dabe nicht erwähnt wird... mei... man kann nicht alles haben. Die Form der Hand zu erwähnen, wirkt, meine ich, zu künstlich.

Comment: Es ging mir gerade um eine Formulierung, in der explizit beschrieben wird, wie die Hand geformt wird.

Comment: @FredBob   Aber warum? Man legt die Hand immer in dieser Form hinters Ohr, denn das ist von der gewünchsten Funktion bestimmt. Niemand legt sich eine Faust hinters Ohr. Die Muschelform ist also der erwartbare Fall, und darum wird sie in der Praxis nie erwähnt.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Google mal Fotos zu "Hand am Ohr" oder so. Da kommen viele unterschiedliche Handhaltungen, teilweise mit nach hinten gewölbter Hand oder aufgefächerten Fingern (wie in meinem Beispielbild). Genau deshalb möchte ich die Form der Hand, die ich meine genau beschreiben.